# Is it possible for a sysadmin to eavesdrop a user's screen/graphics?

Tags: x11, security, privacy

I am interested in several things:
- is it possible?
- how to do it?
- is there a way for a sysadmin to configure
  the machine so that it will beep or send
  an e-mail to the user so that he is aware that someone
  is watching his screen.

I am interested in Linux primarily.
If there are general guidelines for BSDs, I am interested in them too.

I think doing this is illegal in many countries.
I suspect one of my bosses was doing it in the past.
As a user, I'd like to know how to configure the machine to defend against this.
As a sysadmin, I feel doing this is completely unethical.

Comment: "I think doing this is illegal in many countries." source? and you might think it's unethical, but it probably comes under the usage rules in various workplaces. if warning is given to the employee and the admin only uses it to check security/equipment usage, i don't see much wrong.

Comment: Different people have a different ethic.

Comment: I know, That's why I said "you might think". Pointing out the obvious doesn't achieve much.

Comment: I used to work with a program called ObserveIT that would record both windows and linux machines with an agent that could be "hidden".  The company I worked for used it but only on servers and all the admins knew it was there.  Also I completely disagree with your assessment of the ethics.  Every company I have worked for has a login banner that mentions how everything you are doing is being monitored.

Answer (score 6):

### technical feasibility

It certainly is possible for a sysadmin with root privileges to basically access everything that is going on in the machine. One example which I could think of is for a graphical session to use VNC to monitor the current X session, e.g. with [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/). A console session can be read using the terminal devices on unix/linux systems. If not for any of these approaches, basically the whole memory of the machine is available to root in a default setup.

If the sysadmin is willing to show that he is watching the screen then this can be either paired with a custom script to "send email/chat-message and log in" in one step or just execute "echo -e '\a'" to make the computer beep.

### detection of "being watched"

Of course, as an experienced user you can watch out for incoming connections to the machine. Logged in users can be seen e.g. for ssh/telnet-users with the "who" command. Then, open ports tell how the machine can be accessed at all from outside. More low-level would be network traffic monitoring observing in-/outcoming traffic for "suspicious" packets.

### ethical perspective

Basically, root access comes with the fundamental acceptance of trust that users need to provide to the sysadmin. Probably that is a good reason why a "Boss" should not have root access to the machine of a coworker but a third person, a trusted sysadmin.
Good sysadmins will ask users before they access any private data including a live user session. My personal opinion is that upfront communication is more suitable here, i.e. asking the observed user personally, over phone, chat message, email, etc. before making the connection. Software tailored for "remote support" commonly has means of informing the user if not asking for permission, e.g. with a status window telling that someone is connected.